¿Cómo hago para instalar el flask session en vscode?
Tengo una duda del por qué me muestra un error el cual no me deja descargar el flask session, pongo en la terminal:
pip install flask-session

Y me muestra este error:

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for msgspec
Failed to build msgspec
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (msgspec)


https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask
